# Getting list of unique special characters

Tags: python, unicode, special-characters

I want to obtain a list of all the unique characters in a text. A particularity of the text is that it includes composed characters like s̈, b̃. So when I split the text, the special characters are separated. For example, this character s̈ is separated into two characters s and ¨.

This is an example of the text I want to process.

```
sentence = "nejon ámas̈hó T̃iqu c̈ab̃op"
print(sentence)
print(list[set(sentence)])
```

I want to obtain a list with the unique characters. For this sentence, this list should be

expected_list = ['a', 'á', 'b̃', 'c̈', 'e', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'ó', 'p', 'q', 's̈', 'T̃', 'u'  ]

but it is

actual_list = ['j', 'p', 'c', 'n', 'a', ' ', 'i', 'á', 'o', 'T', 'u', '̃', 'h', '̈', 'q', 's', 'e', 'm', 'b', 'ó']

I was reading that I can normalize the special characters as follows

```
import unicodedata
# Only for the character s̈
print(ascii(unicodedata.normalize('NFC', '\u0073\u00a8')))  #prints 's\xa8'
```

But I don't know how to continue. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Handling composed characters in Python can be a bit tricky due to the nature of how they are encoded. Try the `grapheme` library, which specifically deals with grapheme clusters (textual units that are displayed as a single character)

Install the `grapheme` library using pip:

```bash
pip install grapheme
```

or I prefer this way (to make sure it's installing to the current python binary dirs)

```bash
python3 -m pip install grapheme
```

Then, you can use it to extract the unique grapheme clusters from the sentence:

```py
import grapheme

sentence = "nejon ámas̈hó T̃iqu c̈ab̃op"
unique_characters = list(grapheme.graphemes(sentence))

print(unique_characters)
```

Comment: Be aware that the grapheme module hasn't been updated for over three years, so it's data will be obsolete. Whether that is an issue depends on what your likely character inventory is likely to be. Alternatives would be to use the the regex module (not re) and use the \X metacharacter.

Comment: I wouldn't say obsolete as it worked for the exact string OP offered as example, deprecated maybe, but most alphabets have not added new characters in the past three years.

Comment: It is an unmaintained module. With Unicode support, anything not covered explicitly by the stability policy can and does change. There is always new data, the underlying algorithms do change. For instance some databases for xpwrienced breaking changes between Unicode versions. So yes obsolete. I know parts of python follow Unicode, parts diverge, and parts aren't based on Unicode at all. And the module may address this specific question, but may not address the full data set and is not a general answer.

Comment: AS to alphabetic characters, new ones are always being added. I am collaborating on a few proposals at teh moment. I have colleagues who have worked on many over the last few years. True Pythons's definition of an alphabetic character differs form Unicode's. True that alphabetic characters are a subset of word forming characters. True that Python's definition of word forming characters is extremely different from Unicode's. But the devil is in the detail, as the expression goes.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively to @bcstryker's answer.
The only drawback of my code is that, it works with unicode characters with size 1 and 2.

```
import unicodedata


new_list = list()
pass_ = False # To ignore the unicode letters of size 2 from re-iterating

for i, x in enumerate(sentence):
    if x == ' ': # Ignoring space
        continue

    if pass_:
        pass_ = False
        continue

    if (i+1) != len(sentence):
        n_sen = sentence[i+1]
        if 'combining' in unicodedata.name(n_sen).lower(): # Checks if the characters is the unicode letter of size 2
            pass_ = True
            if x+n_sen in new_list: # Checks if the letter already exists in the list
                continue
            new_list += list([x+n_sen]) # Adds the unicode character combined
            continue

    if x in new_list: # Checks if the letter already exists in the list
        continue
    new_list += x # Adds ascii letter and single size unicode special characters

print(new_list)
```

OUTPUT:

> ['n', 'e', 'j', 'o', 'á', 'm', 'a', 's̈', 'h', 'ó', 'T̃', 'i', 'q',
> 'u', 'c̈', 'b̃', 'p']

Answer (score 1):

The question requires splitting the string into grapheme clusters, returning unique graphemes. Duplicate graphemes, punctuation and whitespace are removed.

To get graphemes, you can use the `grapheme` module, but this module has not been updated for 3 years, so it uses an older version of Unicode. Instead I will use the `regex` module with a regular expression pattern for graphemes.

When processing the graphemes , it is necessary to take into account canonical equivalence. If the combining marks belong to different combining combining classes, it is possible to form multiple graphemes that are technically the same grapheme, but consist of different Unicode codepoints. This can be handled by `unicodedata.normalize()`, but the version of Unicode supported is dependant on the version of Unicode being used. In the code below, I will use a more current drop in replacement `unicodedataplus`.

The graphemes in the question require a non standard sort, The code below uses the CLDR collation algorithm, using PyICU. It is possible to build a more complex collation key function using core functions, but I will use the simplier code via PyICU. This requires `icu4c` being available on your computer.

```py
import regex as re
import unicodedataplus as ud
from icu import Collator, Locale

collator = Collator.createInstance(Locale.getRoot())

def get_unique_graphemes(text, collator=None):
    text = ud.normalize("NFC", text)
    text = re.sub(r'[\p{Z}\p{P}]+', '', text)
    result = list(set(re.findall(r'\X', text)))
    if collator:
        result.sort(key=collator.getSortKey)
    return result

sentence = "nejon ámas̈hó T̃iqu c̈ab̃op"
print(get_unique_graphemes(sentence))
# ['á', 'a', 'T̃', 'b̃', 'p', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'q', 'j', 's̈', 'ó', 'i', 'u', 'e', 'c̈', 'h']
print(get_unique_graphemes(sentence, collator))
# ['a', 'á', 'b̃', 'c̈', 'e', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'ó', 'p', 'q', 's̈', 'T̃', 'u']
```

**Edit:**

Rather than using a mixture of modules, I have rewritten the solution above to just use PyICU:

```py
from icu import Collator, Locale, Normalizer2, RegexMatcher, UnicodeString
sentence = "nejon ámas̈hó T̃iqu c̈ab̃op"
def get_unique_graphemes(text, collator=None):
    text = Normalizer2.getNFCInstance().normalize(text)
    text = RegexMatcher('[\\p{Z}\\p{P}]+', UnicodeString(text), 0).replaceAll('')
    ma = RegexMatcher('\\X', UnicodeString(text), 0)
    results = []
    while ma.find():
        results.append(ma.group())
    results = list(set(results))
    if collator:
        results.sort(key=collator.getSortKey)
    return results
collator = Collator.createInstance(Locale.getRoot())
uGraphemes = get_unique_graphemes(sentence, collator)
print(uGraphemes)
# ['a', 'á', 'b̃', 'c̈', 'e', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'ó', 'p', 'q', 's̈', 'T̃', 'u']
```